# Create Windows Form EXE Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

how i can create EXE setup program for Windows Form application Using InstallShield

and i have found this errors

[image]

Comment: Please share the code and exact errors that are occurring. Links are not an acceptable way to include this information on SO.

Comment: this is not code , it's screenshot for the error from the blog

Comment: Well, looking at that screenshot, it looks like you are missing some files. Other than that, its going to be very hard to help you without a lot more information.

Comment: you can tell me how i can create the exe file from visual 2013

Comment: You create a exe from visual studio 2013 by *building*. Installers are very complicated, so telling you how to make one is beyond the scope of an SO question/answer. I can't help you find missing files from an open source article, so I don't see how you *can* be helped at the moment, at least with the information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 you can open the project solution there and make the exe setup there without having to install an install shield. The Steps would be as follows:

1. Click File >> ADD >> Project
2. Select the Setup Wizard and change the fie name >> Click OK
3. Wizard form will pop-up >> Click Next >> Select "Create a Setup for windows application"
4. Click "Primary Output from MDI_CSharp" >> Click next >> ADD All the files related to your project specially the key components. >> Click Next & Finish

If you want to push through with Visual Studio 2012 I would suggest that you double check all the files and make sure the files are in the specified file location. Also don't put the files too deep in subsets of folders (this makes it harder for the program to look it up/find).

I found an article much like your but it contains some details and steps not given on the article that you used. [Here's a link to it](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2014/02/how-to-create-setup-project-in-visual.html).